Using JSSIP to test SIP login credentials
In my web application, the user provides his SIP credentials and I want to test that they are valid using JSSIP to establish a connection to his VOIP provider and then unregister. This is the code I have so far but it doesn't work because there's a web socket connection error JsSIP.js?c=9391:9 JsSIP:WARN:WebSocketInterface invalid WebSocket URI.
What would I need to change to make it work?
function PhoneTestSIPLogin() {

    UserSIPLoginCredentials['SIPLoginServer'] = ''; //enter test value
    UserSIPLoginCredentials['SIPLoginUsername'] = ''; //enter test value
    UserSIPLoginCredentials['SIPLoginPassword'] = ''; //enter test value

    var TheTestSocket = new window['JsSIP']['WebSocketInterface']('wss://' + UserSIPLoginCredentials['SIPLoginServer']);

    var TheTestConfiguration = {
        'sockets': [TheTestSocket],
        'uri': 'sip:' + UserSIPLoginCredentials['SIPLoginUsername'] + '@' + UserSIPLoginCredentials['SIPLoginServer'],
        'password': UserSIPLoginCredentials['SIPLoginPassword'],
        'register': true
    };

    var TheTestUserAgent = new window['JsSIP']['UA'](TheTestConfiguration);

    TheTestUserAgent['start']();

    TheTestUserAgent.on('registered', () => {

        alert('SIP credentials are correct!');
        TheTestUserAgent['unregister']();
        TheTestUserAgent['stop']();
    });

    TheTestUserAgent.on('registrationFailed', (e) => {

        alert('Registration failed:', e.cause);
        TheTestUserAgent['stop']();
    });

    TheTestUserAgent.on('unregistered', () => {

        alert('Unregistered from the SIP server.');
        TheTestUserAgent['stop']();
    });
}



this is a warning, not an error. Does the WSS connection actually establish? You can confirm on the SIP side with something like sip show peer ...

It's an error. I'm normally using jssip to connect to my Freeswitch server which then connects to the VOIP provider with these credentials. But here I'm trying to connect directly to the VOIP provider, not to actually make a call but just to test that the credentials work.

After a look to jssip and esp grammar part, the reportFailures = 0 is inactive, could you try a hack in order to see why the URI is invalid?

@tomrtc: what steps do you recommend trying? The credentials work fine when doing a PTSN call via Freewitch so  I know the information is correct.

I do not think credentials is the problem ; from the text error message and according to the source code its is a URI parsing error but I do not see any problem. Pretty sure the message is not sent at all to the server.
I suspect a trivial problem somewhere else, hope this help.

I can't figure out how to test it. Does this do anything?

I forget to say it explitly but put the variable reportFailures = 1 in jssip.js ofc

look like debug is documented see https://jssip.net/documentation/api/debug/

@AnstonSorensen: if you have a VOIP account, you can test the code with your credentials.

Yeah I tried that. I just couldn’t get the file to run. Does my code do anything?

@AnstonSorensen: yes, the code should trigger the alert statements tied to the event handlers

@AnstonSorensen: your pastebin would need to execute the function in order to see anything.

Edit : actually, the author said in comment the uri is populated with actual data so it is not the root cause.
However, the uri construction line is incorrect imo because uri configuration parameter must be quoted according to documentation:
uri      : 'sip:alice@example.com',
using alternative quote should do the trick:
uri = "'sip:alice.example.com'"
Funny it was obvious, the uri is not correct for a valid reason there is none.
In jssip terminoly, auri is a SIP URI reprensenting the AOR of a the SIP user.
note: just pretend AOR is the business card style address in SIP.
In you source code nothing is set :
 UserSIPLoginCredentials['SIPLoginServer'] = ''; //enter test value
 UserSIPLoginCredentials['SIPLoginUsername'] = ''; //enter test value
 UserSIPLoginCredentials['SIPLoginPassword'] = ''; //enter test value
    

fill in with somthing looking like this:
UserSIPLoginCredentials['SIPLoginServer'] = 'example.com'; //enter test value
UserSIPLoginCredentials['SIPLoginUsername'] = 'alice'; //enter test value
UserSIPLoginCredentials['SIPLoginPassword'] = 'password'; //enter test value

The credentials are correctly entered in the function, I just left them blank in the question because I didn't want them visible online. If you have a VOIP account, you can try the code with your own credentials.

Isn’t it obvious that you’re supposed to put in the credentials to make it work? Are you saying you got it to work as soon as you put them in?

Oh sorry, next time put something irrelevant in the fields at least. This come back to tracing jssip in details after all the uri is the root cause but you have not provided what are those values .
You should check the values of the aor and esp spurious characters.
Try also with a special aor like alice@server.invalid and check if the error is the same or not.

I tried your suggestion of adding quotes: now it fails right away with a CONFIGURATION error.

Oh you should dump those objects TheTestConfiguration and TheTestUserAgent on console.
We are maybe on a wrong path ...

hum I have just seen that check in the code, do you have a domain defined:
target = JsSIP.Utils.normalizeURI(target, this.ua.configuration.domain);
try {
target = JsSIP.Utils.normalizeURI(target, this.ua.configuration.domain);
} catch(e) {
target = JsSIP.C.INVALID_TARGET;
}

Ensure the SIP provider supports WebSocket transport and provides a valid WebSocket URI (e.g., wss://sip.example.com/ws).
Ensure the SIP server allows connections from your domain. If not, you’ll encounter a CORS error in the browser.
Ensure that both SIPLoginUsername and SIPLoginServer are populated with valid values.
Enable JsSIP debugging by adding this before starting the User Agent:
window.JsSIP.debug.enable('JsSIP:*');


As they said, check if the WebSocket is valid, you can check using postman
